# .net string cache/pool

Tags: c#

Does .net sting class support cache/pool mechansism to reduce allocation overhead?

Comment: If you make the question title more clear and add some additional applicable tags you can make it more discoverable by search if anyone else ever has the same basic question (which can mean additional votes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String literals are interned, if that's what you're talking about:

```
string x = "hello";
string y = "hel" + "lo";
string z = "h" + "ello";

bool a = object.ReferenceEquals(x, y);
bool b = object.ReferenceEquals(y, z);
```

Both `a` and `b` are guaranteed to be true.

You can call [`string.Intern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx) yourself, too.

However as far as normal strings go (for example, the string object returned by `string.Format`), the answer would be no, they're not cached by default.  But you could either create your own cache or intern them if you absolutely must.  As many strings are short-lived, I suspect that in most cases it's not worth caching.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I am talking about normal strings. For eg: the string object returned by string.Format

Comment: @Maanu: Then no, they're not cached by default. But you could either create your own cache, or intern them if you absolutely must. As many strings are short-lived, I suspect that in most cases it's not worth caching.

Comment: The downside of string.Intern is that it's permanent, so it keeps a copy of the string around for the life of the AppDomain even after there are no further references to it by your code.  Outside of certain scenarios where that's actually what you want, it can be a bit of a memory leak.

Comment: @Rob: Yup. Typically it's better to keep a `HashSet<String>` or something similar.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: To allow normal garbage collection you can't hold a reference to the string.  Thus you can't key the lookup by the string itself (and you can't key the hash table by a WeakReference, either, since that could become valueless at any time).  See the article on codeproject linked in my answer for how we solved those issues.

Comment: @Rob: Not sure I follow you about the inability to key the hash table by a weak reference... although you'd certainly want a wrapper class to handle the case of the key losing its value. But in many cases you know when you can just ditch the cache completely. It does depend on the situation, of course.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Read the article if you haven't already; that may explain it better.  A WeakReference can't be a key because it isn't an immutable value (what happens to the hash table when the values that it's using as various keys are lost, eh?).  You have to get a bit clever with it.

Comment: @Rob: Hmm... I'll read the article, but I wouldn't expect it to be a problem in this case... because you don't really *want* to find the value anyway, once it's been collected. Obviously you need to perform appropriate clean-up on the dictionary periodically, but the actual cache lookup should be okay, if necessarily slightly odd... (Slightly later - I've now read the article, and it doesn't go into the details of that.)

Answer (score 5):

.NET doesn't do it for you, but we wrote a class with straightforward usage to help do this which is posted in an [article over on codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/StringReference.aspx) (includes the implementation of our Single Instance String Store).  We use this ourselves internally in [Gibraltar](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/) to reduce the memory impact, particularly in the Gibraltar.Agent library which is designed to be safely included with our customers' production applications.

The class allows you to consolidate any reference to a string so that each unique string value shares the same copy among all references that have been consolidated, but it still allows that copy to be garbage collected automatically when all of your references to it have been dropped.  The small overhead of each WeakReference and the lookup table can be periodically packed.

This works really well for our case, especially, because the Gibraltar.Agent will be handling a large quantity of various strings passing through it as metrics and logging data, some of which may stick around a long time and need many references while others may be used only once and never needed again.  It's particularly beneficial when you often recompute the same effective string value because run-time generation of the same value will always end up with a new reference, but the string store can be used to immediately replace that with your "official" copy for that value.

It may not be as useful in some applications such as if most of your strings are in references that aren't as accessible or practical to replace, such as in DataSets.